# How can I access SQL Server Management Studio from Visual Studio 2013, or otherwise run Stored Procs?

Tags: stored-procedures, visual-studio-2013, ssms, linqpad

[This link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms239722.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) says I can connect to a SQL Server database "from either SQL Server Object Explorer or the Data Connections node in Server Explorer. SQL Server Object Explorer provides a view that is like SQL Server Management Studio."

What I need is to see and run Stored Procs in a database instance (from SQL Server Object Explorer, I can see the Tables, but not the Stored Procs).

Rather than simply "a view that is like SQL Server Management Studio" how can I get "the real thing"?

Actually, anything that will allow me to provide the necessary parameters and see the results is fine, but my "go-to tool" for querying the database (LINQPad) doesn't seem to understand Stored Procs, other than just displaying them.

So how can I access SQL Server Management Studio from Visual Studio 2013, so that I can see and execute the Stored Procs?

### UPDATE

Here is what I see with SQL Server Object Explorer (no Stored Procs):

[image]

Here is what I see with LINQPad (the Stored Procs are shown, but 2-clicking one simply adds it with ellipsis dots):

[image]

Comment: Hope this video links will be helped to you :) 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iv2ztA1md_g

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xUU9MdnohrI

Good luck :D

Comment: FYI—In a sense, SSMS is Visual Studio: It's built on the same Visual Studio shell; it's just a different product. Where this helps is that the extension model is the same. An extension just has to say which products it should be installed into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Management Studio is a stand alone program that is not accessed from Visual Studio.

SQL Server Management Studio does allow you to examine stored procedures and execute them.

After starting SQL Server Management Studio and connecting to the database with the stored procedures, expand the **"Programmability"** folder to see the "Stored Procedures" folder.

[image]

To execute a stored procedure, expand the "Stored Procedures" folder, right click on the stored procedure of interest and select "Execute Stored Procedure ...". (If your stored procedure requires input parameter inputs, you'll be prompted for those. Be careful doing this, I suggest doing s SELECT SP and not a DELETE.)

[image]

To see the stored procedure definition, use the "Script Stored Procedure as" - "CREATE To" - "New Query Editor Window" command.

[image]

Note, the prior images were taken from the 2008 version of SQL Server Management Studio. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

Stored Procs are available under SQL Server Object Studio's "Programmability" subfolder.

After expanding that, locating the Stored Proc, and selecting "Execute Procedure" from the context menu, you can provide values for the parameters in the "Execute Stored Procedure" dialog:

[image]

So, from Visual Studio 2013:

```
Select View > SQL Server Object Explorer
Select the appropriate database
Expand Programmability
Right-click the Stored Proc and select "Execute Stored Procedure"
Provide the parameters you want to test in the "Value" column
Select the "OK" button
```